# Executing code after jquery call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Lets say I have the following js code

```
$(function() {
   $('#some_id').load('myfile.html', function() {
      alert('Call back called');
   });

  alert('You should alert second');
  // more javascript code .........

});
```

For some reason, `alert('Call back called');` is the last thing that gets alerted to me. I thought that js code executes in the order of the file. Is there a way to make `alert('Call back called');` go first before all my other functions.

Looking at my simple code snippet one would suggest why not put `alert('You should alert second');` in the function call back, unfortunately I  am inheriting a code base that is really big and jamming all those function calls in my callback wont be feasible

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You can use promises to make this easier.

Comment: `alert('You should alert second');` is called immediately when the js is initialized, where the alert('Call back called') will be called only after the .load is called (look into callbacks).

Comment: the callback function of the load() function is thought exactly for this purpose, you should put the code there, there aren't reasons to don't do that.

Comment: You could use `.ajax()` instead of `.load()` and set `async: false` like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re#133327

Comment: When you create a function, do you expect it's contents to execute before you call the function http://pastebin.com/1zSt0vH2? that's kinda what you're expecting out of the above code which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is an asynchronous method, and the anonymous function you passed to it as a parameter is executed ONLY when the asynchronous method finishes executing.

Answer (score 1):

*"I thought that js code executes in the order of the file."*  It does, and that's what's happening here.  But because the `.load()` callback function is, well, a callback (i.e. only fires once the asynchronous operations is complete) `alert('Call back called');` will only fire when it's invoke at some point in the future.

Comment: Here's a basic demo of the concept you're explaining http://pastebin.com/1zSt0vH2

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others, load is an async method, hence you need to use something like a synchronous AJAX call. Use it this way:

```
$.ajax({
     url:    'myfile.html',
     async:   false
     success: function(result) {
                  alert('Call back called');
              }
});

alert('You should alert second');
```

Comment: I agree. If you downvote something please leave a comment. This seems like a good way to replace the asynchronic method, worth a try.

Comment: I guess the down vote because it did not work. I tried but had no luck with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which deals with asynchronous calls for you. Doing so your code will be executed in the reading order, no matter when the response is sent back :

```
$(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.get('myfile.html', function(data) {
        $('#some_id').html(data);
        alert('Call back called');
    });
    jqxhr.done(function() { 
        alert('You will alert second');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **pure javascript**, just add a function with a **callback** argument for the stuff coming in the second `alert()` area:

```
$(function() {

   function someCode (callback) {
     $('#some_id').load('myfile.html', function() {
       alert('Call back called');
       // add parameters, if you like
       callback();
     });
   }

   function someMoreCode() {
     alert('You should alert second');
     // more javascript code .........
   }

   // And Finally...
   someCode(someMoreCode);

});
```

Comment: Nice, but you should call `callback` inside `load`'s callback. Moreover, you don't have to wrap the `load` call inside a function, just declare `callback` somewhere and use it.

Comment: 1. Why? 2. Example? It would be helpful if you explained your points beyond stating what should be done and what not. I actually liked your solution, but wanted to give one which works without jQuery. So why vote down?

Comment: Your code produces exactly the same result than his code. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `alert('You should alert second');` to happen second you need to call it from within your callback function:

```
$(function() {
   $('#some_id').load('myfile.html', function() {
      alert('Call back called');
      alert('You should alert second');
   });

});
```